# SSH: correct passwords stopped working, lead to connection termination

Tags: linux, ssh, passwords

I have a VDS under Linux which I used to log in to via SSH for several years.

Recently after providing a correct password I've started to get "Server unexpectedly closed network connecton".
It happens particularly when the password is correct. When it is any but correct, the answer is usual "Access denied". I'm certain at this, because I have many user accounts at this VDS and I tried it with a few of them.

I didn't change anything in sshd configuration from the time when everything was ok.

We rebooted the whole VDS after the problem occured but it didn't help.

Any ideas on why did it happen and what to do?

Comment: possible reason : password ageing, version of ssh, allowed ssh protocol in serverr and client.

Comment: @Archemar
Same server and client (putty, actually) were used all the time.
Passwords were made with no expiration date; also the user accounts were created at different times so they shouldn't expire at the same moment anyway